# How to determine cross section of cable

Tags: voltage, power, amperage, conductors, wire-size

I'm looking at this table that suggests a 0.5mm2 cable could withstand 720W at 3A.

[image]

At the same time I used a cable size calculator online to determine the size of cable I would need to use for a 12V60A which is also 720W and it gave me 8mm2 as the result.

And thinking about it, it does make sense as current is a measure of electrons per unit time, being physical objects (not quite but I come from a programming background so that also makes sense to me) the more they are the more space they would need to move through. But where is the voltage in the equation, if we imagine voltage being the strength with which the electrons are moving it would also make sense to need a stronger conductor the higher the voltage and it doesn't seem to be the case? Is conductor cross section determined solely by amperage? Could a 0.5mm2 cable carry 3A at any voltage?

Quite a bunch of questions I posed there but I hope you get where my curiosity is coming from.

Comment: There are plenty of tables on the internet, choose several and make comparisons. From the details in your question, it makes no sense to specify power.

Comment: Can you share a link to where you found the table you included in the question?

Comment: @ThePhoton I grabbed it from google without opening the site, turns out it's [a product on amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Meters-White-0-75mm-3183Y-Flexible/dp/B00BELL2OC), not quite what you'd expect I suppose :D

Comment: depends on heat-removal ability. Uninsulated, in air, and short length will be much better than a long insulated wire inside a bundle of similarly-heated cables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required wire size is determined by the current it is expected to carry, not by voltage or power.  The voltage will determine the required insulation thickness or type.

The required wire size for a given current is determined by both resistance heating and voltage drop in the wire resistance

Comment: I suppose you are correct, but my question was more of why it is that way.

Comment: The wire only knows about the current it is carrying - it doesn't know about the voltage, or power required by the load.  In North American house wiring, #14 wire is good for 15 Amp, whether the load is 120 or 240 V.

Comment: @php_nub_qq the wire is not the load, therefor it will not have the main part of the voltage across it. The load will. The wire will however have the same current as the load. The voltage across the wire depends on length and cross section, where as the heat generated due to current can ignore the length part and just look at the cross section of the wire.

Comment: @PeterBennett but that doesn't make sense to me. If we take for an analogy a pipe through which a liquid is flowing - the pipe being the wire and the liquid the electrons - then if we want to increase the amount of liquid going through the pipe (assuming we can not change the speed, because we can't change the speed the electrons flow with I assume), we must increase its cross section. However if we want to increase the pressure (the voltage) we would need to make sure the pipe is strong enough, which is not the case with electricity?

Comment: @HarrySvensson ^

Comment: @php_nub_qq: In the water analogy, the hole in the pipe corresponds to the wire itself, while the pipe wall corresponds to the insulation on the wire.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fact that table says 2400W at 10A, the voltage must be 240V mains then. But you need 60A, you need wire that can carry it. 0.5 square millimeter can carry 3A.